# ad timer focus required

Tags: timer, focus

hi    i want to show a timer that will stop if the window/tab is not in focus and when the user will back to the window/tab it will again start to countdown. i have following code and i tried some methods but not getting the desired result!hope one of you will able to solve my problem

```
 function adTimer() {
    timer++;
    if(timer == fulltimer) {
        var show="Click <img src=\"clickimages/"+key+".png\">";
        $("#buttons").fadeIn();
        $("#timer").html(show);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(adTimer, 1000);
    }
    $("#bar").width((timer/fulltimer)*200);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(id != -1) adTimer();
    else $("#timer").html("Cheat Check");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for focus with a timer:

```
var focus;

function mytimer() {
  if (focus) {
    // Do stuff.
    alert("test");
  }
}

$(window).blur(function () {
  focus = false;
});

$(window).focus(function () {
  focus = true;
});

setInterval(mytimer, 1000);
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3nwU/2)

Comment: i don't know java script so don't understand your code .i will be highly glad if you show me how to do this with my code !i mean do i need to edit anything or i will just ad your code before my code?

Comment: Click on the "Fiddle" link.

Comment: i click fiddle tried to run but no change !! only showing       this code          var focus;
var key = 0;

function mytimer() {
    if (focus) {
        key++;
        alert(key);
    }
}

$(window).blur(function () {
    focus = false;
});

$(window).focus(function () {
    focus = true;
});

setInterval(mytimer, 1000);

Comment: Try it again, it missed JQuery, it will work now. (Click somewhere in the code or outside the window to stop the popups)

Comment: did not help at all i said you i don't know java script.it would be helpful if you showed me how to use this with my code.Did u ever see a ptc site(paid to click) where user earn for viewing a ad for a certain time if the user switches to  another window the timer paused and when he comes back the timer resumes,actually i am trying to implement this type of focus.